# Always on speech recognition while in app, android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, speech-recognition

I'm trying to make some sort of a voice assistant, I won't get into too much detail about my project itself as its in very early development so whatever suggestions work I will work my app around them.

I want to make a speech recognition module that starts listening onCreate and continues listening as long as the user is in my app(i dont want it to listen after they exit/minimalise the app).

I'm aware it would have to loop as I can't make it listen forever I'm also aware it would have flaws but im not bothered as it's for my personal usage.

I'm currently writing the app in java but I am willing to switch to kotlin if there's a way to make it work there.(I don't know much about how kotlin works so if this sounds dumb then really sorry)

I've tried to put speechRecognizer.startListening inside of the onSpeechEnded() function but it seems not to work as expected since after a certain amount of time it won't register my speech anymore.

Comment: Some code is needed here so others can understand what you are doing and offer ways to help.

Comment: Like I said I can fully adapt my code to ANY solutions there are, whatever someone says I'll try to work with, my code is such a mess from all my attempts anyways that it probably makes no sense now anyways